Does changing units affect Significant Figures
Does changing the unit of a physical quantity has no influence whatsoever on the number of significant figures?
Suppose the mass of a particle is given as 0.060kg
0.060 has 2 significant figures as nonzero digits and trailing zeroes after decimal point are considered significant
When the same mass is converted to grams , it becomes 60g which has just 1 significant figure.
In 60 trailing zeroes precede the decimal point and are hence not counted in the number of significant figures
I tried to manually multiply 0.060 by 1000 writing it as 0060.000g which has 5 significant figures. Hence the attempt failed as 0.060kg had just 2 significant figures
How do we ensure that the number of significant figures doesn't change due to unit conversions, especially when the measurements involve trailing zeroes after the decimal point?

Does changing units affect Significant Figures
It should not.
There will always be a doubt about the significance of the zeros other than as placeholders with values greater than $10$ like $60\,\rm kg, 600\,\rm kg, 6000\, \rm kg, \dots$ unless extra information is given.
Using "engineer's notation", eg $6.0 \times 10^1\,\rm kg,\,6.00 \times 10^2\,\rm kg,\,6.000 \times 10^3\,\rm kg,\dots$ with the appropriate number of significant zeros could be one way to reduce the ambiguity.
Another way could be by choosing an "appropriate" multiplier for the unit so that the numerical value is less than $10$, eg $0.060\,\rm Mg,\,0.600\,\rm Mg,\,6.000\,\rm Mg,\,\dots$
